# What is the name of this snakes-and-ladders-like race game?

Tags: identify-this-game

Someone taught me a game that they remember playing many years before. They drew the board from memory, it looks mostly like this:

```
 _____________
|  __________ |
| |E|   |   | |
| | | | | | | |
| | |<| |<| | |
| | | | | | | |
|S|___|___|___|
```

Each player began at the start (S), took turns to roll the dice and move, to see who could read the end (E) first. In some places, there were shortcuts (<) allowing players to move ahead more quickly.

Comment: I think I saw a board like this recently. Do you know/remember any graphical details from the board? Was the game connected in any way with snake and ladders in design?What I mean is: where there snakes on the board? Ladders?

Comment: I never saw the original board. I saw some Chinese people playing it, but they had quickly drawn the board by hand on some graph paper and I don't know how well they had recreated it from their memory. I think they used Chinese characters to indicate the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a classic game in Spain called "El juego de la Oca", which in english is known as the "[Game of The Goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_the_Goose)". There are thousands of variants for the board (including bridges, ladders etc.), so maybe you saw a Chinese version

Answer (score -3):

I remember playing it when I was young. Here is wikipedia entry for it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_Ladders

Comment: The question asked for a game that was *like* Snakes and Ladders.